# How do I paginate an html table created from an array?

Tags: php, pagination, html-table

I am having trouble thinking of the right logic and approach to separating my data and dynamically creating a table with pagination. I have a function that reads the file server, compiles a list of images and sorts them into an array like this:

```
imagenames ( [0] => apple.png [1] => banana.png [2] => carrot.png [3] => dill.png )
```

I use this array to dynamically create a table with a code like this :

```
echo '<table>';
for ($r=0; $r<$rows; $r++){
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($c=0; $c<$cols; $c++){
        if($index<$imagecount){
            echo '<td><img src="images/'.$imagenames[$index].'" ></td>';
            $index++;
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}   
echo '</table>';
```

If I set `$rows=3;` and `$cols=3;`, my table will have room for 9 images. If my array had lets say 50 images, how would I go about paginating the the table so I have a next, previous and a numbered menu so that the whole table does not have to load all at once or ignore all the files outside of the scope defined by `$rows*$cols`?

*EDIT**   ------->>>

So if I go with something that Steven Liao suggests and have this:

```
$size = $rows*$cols; // number of elements on page
$min = $_GET['p']*$size; // start index in array
$total_pages = ceil(count($imagenames)/$size); 

echo '<table class="photobox">';
   for ($r=0; $r<$rows; $r++){
      echo '<tr>';
      for ($c=0; $c<$cols; $c++){
    if($index<$imagecount){
       echo '<td><img src="images/'.$imagenames[$index].'" /></td>';
       $index++;
    }
      }
      echo '</tr>';
   }    
echo '</table><br/><br/>';

// Previous
$prev_page = max($_GET['p']-1, 0);
echo '<a href="photobox.php?p='.$prev_page.'">Previous</a>';
// Each individual page number (no separators yet)
for($i = 0; $i < $total_pages; $i++){
    echo '<a href="photobox.php?p='.$i.'">'.($i+1).'</a>';
}
// Next
$next_page = min($_GET['p']+1,$total_pages-1);
echo '<a href="photobox.php?p='.$next_page.'">Next</a>';
```

This Displays the table and creates the navigation links. How would i go about making the table content change with each page. The navigation is there and the URL changes with the pages but the table does not change and i don't really know this paging code well as it is based off Steven Liao's Answer.

Comment: looks like you should be adding a db, to track the files

Comment: Then with a db, you csn limit the amount of data retrieved from the server using the LIMIT syntax in SQL

Comment: I don't have any experience with SQL or any databases. I know a db would be ideal for what im asking however i do believe i should be able to achieve pagination with my array of file names without the use of a db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have `$rows×$cols` number of images on each page. So on your first page `$index` would start on 0, on next page start from `1+$page×$rows×$cols` and so on, where `$page` is page nnumber. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: yes i get the idea. I just dont know going about adding logic to my example above. The code above is set to fill a table with the first 9 elements from the $imagenames array. Not only does the table need to change to view more than the first 9 elements i need a navigation to go with it.

Comment: If you got the idea I suggest you try writing some code or markup yourself now.. Then if you get error or something someone can still help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$size = $row*$col; // number of elements on page
$min = $_GET['p']*$size; // start index in array
$total_pages = ceil(count($imagenames)/$size); // round up number of pages (stragglers get their own page)

// Display logic here
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++){
        echo '<span>Display Logic for '.$imagenames[$min+$i*rows+$j].'</span>';
    }
}

// Previous
$prev_page = max($_GET['p']-1, 0);
echo '<a href="this.php?p='.$prev_page.'">Previous</a>';

// Each individual page number (no separators yet)
for($i = 0; $i < $total_pages; $i++){
    echo '<a href="this.php?p='.$i.'">'.($i+1).'</a>';
}

// Next
$next_page = min($_GET['p']+1,$total_pages-1);
echo '<a href="this.php?p='.$next_page.'">Next</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net): jQuery plugin with very simple basic usage:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#your_table_id').dataTable();
});
```

In addition to navigation and pagination you also get multi-column sorting with data detection, and a searchbox.  Support for jQuery UI styles. (Features can be enabled/disabled as required).

NB: Your table must use `thead` an `tbody` elements for this plugin to work properly.

There are multiple other plugins available too.

Comment: This looks like it is more for data information. I am using my table to display images like a gallery.

Comment: @thariddla You can easily use this for images as well.